# creating index from text corpus with llama-index encountering issue import Chatcompletion from openai

Tags: python-3.x, openai-api, large-language-model, llama-index

I have the python code below.  I'm using llama_index to create an index from a text corpus.  I'm then submitting a query to the index to get a response.  I'm getting the error below that it cannot import Chatcompletion from openai.  It looks like llama_index is trying to import it from openai in some step.  This code was working previously on another machine that was running llama-index 0.6.9, this machine is running 0.7.2.  I'm guessing they changed something recently.  Can anyone suggest how to fix this issue?

code:

```
# function to index corpus and get response

def index_response(api_key, text_path,query):
    
    # api key you generate in your openai account
    
    import os
    
    # add your openai api key here
    
    os.environ['OPENAI_API_KEY']=api_key
    
    # Load your data into 'Documents' a custom type by llamaIndex
    from llama_index import SimpleDiretoryReader, Document
    
    with open(text_path,'r') as file:
        
        text_history = file.read()
        
    documents = [Document(text_history)]
    
    from llama_index import GPTVectorStoreIndex
    
    index = GPTVectorStoreIndex.from_documents(documents)
    
    query_engine = index.as_query_engine()
    response=query_engine.query(query)
    
    return response.response
    
    

# initial query

prompt="This is some text to help clarify my search.  "

query1="Here is my question?"

prompt_submit=prompt+query1

# prompt_submit

response_string=index_response(api_key=apikey, 
               text_path='~/path/data/',
               query=prompt_submit)

response_string
```

error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'ChatCompletion' from 'openai' (/home/user/anaconda3/envs/LLMenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/openai/__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade you openai library. Also, make sure after upgrade you are restart your code editor

```
pip install --upgrade openai
```

If you are using Jupyter notebook

```
pip uninstall openai
close kernel (shut down kernel)
open notebook
!pip install --upgrade openai
```